# Discount on Cart page

Tags: commerce

Where in Drupal Commerce does it output the Discount information on the Cart page. I can find the Total Amount but not the Discount. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have to use some additional modules like https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_discount and other which are indicated there.